# LinkedIn API - Not enough permissions to access: POST /people/id={id}/certifications

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use the LinkedIn API to publish a certification to a LinkedIn user's profile. I am using `POST /people/id={id}/certifications` with our LinkedIn app, but I am getting this response:

```
{
  serviceErrorCode: 100,
  message: 'Not enough permissions to access: POST /people/id={id}/certifications',
  status: 403
}
```

I see [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-edit-api/certifications#:%7E:text=The%20use%20of%20this%20API%20is%20restricted%20to%20those%20developers%20approved%20by%20LinkedIn%20and%20subject%20to%20applicable%20data%20restrictions%20in%20their%20agreements.) a note about this API being `restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn`, but I don't see any way for us to request access to this. The documentation does not include any mention of specific scopes required for this API request.

For what it's worth, I've already logged a ticket with LinkedIn support, and they instructed me to post here.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a definitive answer from LinkedIn via partner support:

> As mentioned in our document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api
>
> > The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements.
>
> And the /people endpoint is currently only available with our Compliance partner program. Unfortunately, at this time, the Compliance API Partner Program is not accepting any applications for any new Partners. For context, we grant access to only for vetted Compliance partners that are helping Regulated LinkedIn Members and Customers facilitate regulatory-compliant usage of Social Media.
>
> However, we constantly monitor the ecosystem and prioritize partners that are important to our business and product strategy, thus we may want to revisit this opportunity again in the future.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no API workaround to the above.

If you're wanting to use the LinkedIn `/people` endpoint, please let their partner support team know so we'll all benefit when they decide to open this up.